# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

Need to urgently redirect HTTPS traffic to HTTP

Looked around at various options and am ending up with:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked for what seemed a few minutes but now I am trying to visit our site again and am running into the error that states 'secure connection failed' anytime an HTTPS connection occurs. Note that we no longer have an active certificate assigned as we revoked it (possibly related to our issue?).

The problem here is that nearly all of our traffic shows up via indexed links in Google which are all HTTPS links and we're now going strictly to HTTP.

Any assistance in this matter would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic due to the fact that you're using shared hosting. You may want to try asking your question over on [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but please have a read of their FAQ first to ensure the topicality of your question.

Comment: @EEAA Does shared hosting make questions off topic as a rule now?

Comment: @WesleyDavid it has for quite a while. We send them to [webmasters.se]

Comment: @WesleyDavid - IMHO, yes. In this situation, the OP had no capability to solve the problem the "proper" way from a Sysadmin's perspective, *even if* there was a way to solve the problem through a control panel of some type. If that were the case, it would be better handled by webmasters.SE.

Comment: @EEAA Yeah, I think shared hosting is borderline. However, for this specific case, no mention was made of a control panel, nor was shared hosting, so I was puzzled at the assessment. In this case, it's a simple case of .htaccess wonkery and some regex, which you nailed in the answer.

Comment: @WesleyDavid Yah, OP mentioned Shared hosting in a comment to my answer...

Comment: @EEAA *dun dun* ***dunnnnn***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your SSL virtualhost, just do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. In GoDaddy (using shared hosting) how can I accomplish this? If it's possible. I'm not super familiar with the server related stuff.

Comment: Well, you're using shared hosting, so you're limited to the tools GoDaddy gives you, which very few of us know anything about since we tend to run our own servers rather than use other people's systems.

Comment: Ah, ok. I figured that'd be the issue. Guess I'll just wait it out and see what happens. I'm going to reinstate a new certificate in the meantime to hopefully prevent the traffic from landing on an error page (seemed fine before I revoked the cert) Thanks for the help.